# Keep file permissions on dhcpd.leases after reboot on Linux

Tags: linux, dhcp

We have a Linux machine on which we run our .NET Core app. This app is a web UI which is used to display and configure a system of EEPROMs.
The app reads the dhcpd.leases file, located in the directory /var/lib/dhcp, and displays the IP address of each EEPROM in the UI.

When a new EEPROM is added to the system, its IP address is added to the dhcpd.leases file and thus it shows up in the UI. But when an EEPROM is removed from the system, its IP address isn't removed from the dhcpd.leases file and thus it continues to be shown in the UI.

We want to allow the user to be able to remove an EEPROM from the UI when it has been physically removed from the system.

When a user removes an EEPROM from the UI, we want its IP address to be removed from the dhcpd.leases so that it won't be shown again.

This isn't possible, since the default permissions on the file give read and write permission only to the owner (there's no owner listed), give read-only permission to the dhcpd group and other users, and don't allow it to be executed. By running the command `sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases`, the file permissions can be changed and thus the app is able to modify the file as we want it to. However, whenever the system reboots, the file permissions are reverted. Our Linux machine uses systemd services to start the app whenever the system starts up, so I thought creating a systemd service would be the best way to ensure the command to change the file permissions is executed when the system starts up. I created a file named dhcp.service in the directory /etc/systemd/system which looks like this:

```
[Unit]  
Description=change dhcpd.leases permissions  

[Service]  
Type=oneshot  
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/dhcp  
ExecStart=chmod 777 dhcpd.leases  
User=root  

[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I then ran the command `systemctl enable dhcp.service`. But even after rebooting the system, the file permissions still weren't changed. I ran the command `systemctl is-enabled dhcp.service` and that returned enabled. I also ran `journalctl -u dhcp.service` and the logs showed that the service ran successfully when the system started up. When I run `systemctl start dhcp.service`, the file permissions will successfully change. This service works as it should when it starts, but not when it's enabled, despite the logs showing that it ran successfully. I tried tips from various questions posted here and on other exchange sites but nothing has worked, so I thought I'd share my specific scenario. How can we permanently change the file permissions so that they aren't reverted when the system reboots?

Comment: The question does not seem to be related to programming but to system configuration, so it may be better suited for https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com. Apart from this, plese explain in your question why you want to **modify** `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases`? This file is meant to be used by the DHCP server `dhcpd`. The server may from time to time re-write the file by creating a temporary file and renaming it to `dhcpd.leases`, so any changes to the file might get re-created with permissions defined by the DHCP server or its configuration. This may happen on server start.

Comment: This looks like an XY-problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I don't have a good solution for your use case. Maybe you should use an own table of removed devices in your application. Or maybe you can check if the device is online by something like `ping`. In any case you must not modify the `dhcpd.leases`  file while the DHCP server is running. So the correct way to modify the file (if you really need to) would be 1. stop DHCP server, 2. modify the file, 3. start DHCP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made changes to our systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=change dhcpd.leases permissions
After=isc-dhcp-server.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/dhcp
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30
ExecStart=chown -R whisker:whisker /var/lib/dhcp/
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is a slightly different approach from what we were trying before, but it's a better approach. chmod 777 is dangerous as it makes the file readable, writable, and executable by everyone. This service instead changes the owner of the file, where whisker is the name of the user. The app runs as the user whisker, so now the app is able to read and write the dhcpd.leases file, which is exactly what we want. The owner of the entire /var/lib/dhcp directory must be changed as opposed to just the dhcpd.leases file, according to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/955966/how-do-i-purge-dhcpd-leases). From what we understood, the dhcpd.leases~ file, which has the default permissions, overwrites the dhcpd.leases file from time-to-time, including the permissions that we set. This behavior can be eliminated by changing the owner of the directory. As a result, when the system reboots, the owner of the file doesn't revert.